# How to find Azure 'Management Key' with ACSV2?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm-2011

smart people...

I'm having a devil of a time doing something that I suspect ought to be rather simple, but I'm just thickheaded enough to make it really hard.  I'm trying to set up the Azure Service Bus so I can push a few CRM applications and plugins out into the cloud.

Check out  the image below.  At this point, I have already set up an azure account and a Namespace for my service bus .  The 'top' two windows show where I'm trying to register the service bus as an endpoint in Dynamics CRM 2011, using the plugin registration tool.

What is throwing me is the textbox I have circled.  It's asking for a 'Management Key', but I can't find one.  Where is that?

[image]

Note:  I set the Azure service up on 3/6/2012 so it's ACS V2.  So far, *EVERY* example I have seen makes use of ACS V1 (which, for those who may read this at a later date, has now been deprecated).
When I look at the properties under tha Azure Management Portal, the property called 'Management Key' is indeed there, but it's empty (image below).    How do I get there from here?  :)  Please help!

[image]

Thanks so much!

-R Cisney

Answer (score 7):

For ServiceBus authentication, currently there is only the "Default Issuer" and "Default Key" credentials. Where the issuer is currently always set to "owner". But both you can get from the "Default Keys" section at the right part of the screen when you have your Service Bus NameSpace Selected:

[image]

However I do believe that this dialog, which you show is requiring the ACS management key. And this you can find at the ACS Management portal. You can get to the ACS management portal, once you have created an ACS namespace. Just select the created ACS namespace and then click on "Access Control Service" button at the top navbar:

[image]

Now you are in the ACS managment portal. Navigate to Management service on your left hand navigation links and then you will see the default Managment client account:

[image]

Click on it and you will see the available credentials. The Symmetric key credential is what you are looking for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Lol, this is so convoluted. Good thing there is stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If your application uses the Windows Azure Service Bus, I think it might just be looking for the Default Key that the Service Bus portal provides. Have you tried entering that where it's asking for a "Management Key"?